# Problem building scala 2.13.1 with Gradle 6.2 (worked with 5.6.2)

Tags: scala, gradle

I want to use Gradle 6.2 because of the recently fixed scaladoc issue.

[Here is a build scan](https://gradle.com/s/3tiuw3op4y42i) of my Gradle build using version 5.6.2 and Scala 2.13.1 - which works fine.

Without changing the Gradle build file at all, other than changing the version to 6.2, I now get this error:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':zinc'.
   > Conflict(s) found for the following module(s):
       - org.scala-lang:scala-library between versions 2.12.8, 2.12.2, 2.12.1 and 2.12.0
       - com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java between versions 3.7.0 and 3.3.1
       - org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12 between versions 1.0.6 and 1.0.5
```

I studied the suggested dependency graph but don't know how I am supposed to resolve the conflicts. I don't know why it is trying to use scala 2.12 at all.

[Here is the corresponding build scan](https://gradle.com/s/kwyho5ogmeays) for this failing build.

I see that dependency configurations like "compile" are now deprecated. I tried changing to the newer preferred configurations, but I'm not certain that I mapped them all correctly.
I tried this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "java3d:vecmath:$vecmathVersion"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compileOnly("org.scala-lang:scala-library") {
        version {
            require "2.13.1"
        }
    }
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.1.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.6.0'
}
```

but get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337275/embedded-kafka-scalatest-classnotfoundexception-scala-collection-gentraversable/62982622#62982622) for a bit more detail about how gradle works with Scala dependencies.

I suggest simplifying your dependencies section first, and using a specific version of scala, to get it working.    I don't see why you you only want the scala-library at compile time and not runtime?    The Gradle Scala plugin requires it to be a generally compile-time dependency: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html.
The same documentation says that Gradle uses 2.12 to compile 2.13 sources... so I suspect that the 2.12 dependency is creeping in because you did not explicitly declare your scala-library version.

Without knowing the value of $vecmathVersion, I suggest the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'java3d', name: 'vecmath', version: '1.3.1'
    implementation group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.13.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest', name: 'scalatest_2.13', version: '3.1.1'
    testImplementation 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.6.0'
}
```