# embedded-kafka scalatest ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce

Tags: java, scala, gradle, apache-kafka, scalatest

New to Scala, I'm on step one of implementing a ScalaTest with https://github.com/embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka according to the second example at the top of that **README**:

```scala
import net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafka
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike

class MinimalTest extends AnyWordSpecLike with Matchers {

  "runs with embedded kafka" should {

    "work" in {
      EmbeddedKafka.start()

      1 + 1 shouldBe 2
      // ... code goes here

      EmbeddedKafka.stop()
    }
  }
}
```

Running this test, the failure is at a lower level than I am familiar with:

```sh
MinimalTest:
runs with embedded kafka
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce
  at com.myorganization.api.MinimalTest.$anonfun$new$2(MinimalTest.scala:13)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
  at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike$$anon$3.apply(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1076)
  at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
  at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
  at com.myorganization.api.MinimalTest.$anonfun$new$2(MinimalTest.scala:13)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
  ...
```

I suspect a mismatch of dependency versions, but can't spot it. Here's my relevant **build.gradle** contents:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
}

task spec(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
    args = ['-R', 'build/classes/scala/test', '-o']
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.4.0'
    compile 'io.github.embeddedkafka:embedded-kafka-streams_2.12:2.4.0'
    compile 'io.github.embeddedkafka:embedded-kafka_2.12:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1'
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.6'
    testCompile 'io.github.embeddedkafka:embedded-kafka-schema-registry_2.12:5.4.0' // match schema registry version
    testCompile 'io.github.embeddedkafka:embedded-kafka-streams_2.13:2.4.0' // match kafka streams version
    testCompile 'io.github.embeddedkafka:embedded-kafka_2.13:2.4.0' // match kafka version
    testCompile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.2'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testRuntime 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.4.2'
}
```

Comment: scala-reflect 2.13.2  instead of 2.12.6? And another thing is in your test case make use of beforeandafterall from scalatest

Comment: Thank you! Big Gotcha... the `2.13` in `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:2.4.0` stands for Scala 2.13. So all of those needed to be updated to `2.12`

Answer (score 1):

Gradle can indeed be a bit funny with transitive dependencies for Scala - in the sense that it will not automatically calculate a coherent set of versions.

The "missing" class scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce is part of the scala-library and is available in 2.12.x

So you should be able to fix this by:

- a. Explicitly declaring the scala library version on your runtime classpath:
  `implementation group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.12.6'`
- b. Checking all your other dependencies for 2.13 versions of the libraries (as @ShankarShastri suggested).    Seems like embedded-kafka does have a 2.12 compatible build here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka_2.12/2.5.0

Once you have done this, assuming your IDE is set up to sync with your `build.gradle` file, you should be able to look at the dependencies (declared and transitive) that gradle has calculated.    If you still have problems, go through these manually and see if the `org.scala-lang:scala-library` library is missing or declared twice.    If you have multiple declarations you can look at each library's dependencies in mvncentral.com .

N.B. the reason for step (a) is that you have scala artefacts in your 'compile' dependencies, so I assume that all your code (not just your test code) is using scala.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the fix is validation dependencies. Or more technically check the test dependencies.

For me I upgraded my SpringBoot version which changed my `spring-kafka-test` version which intern included kafka 2.13.x which finally included scala libs.

I used `mvn dependency:tree` on my project's build file and searched for '2.12' to find where the old dependency was coming from. Example dependency tree (unrelated dependencies removed). Notice `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:0.10.0.0` included as part of `my.company.riptide.api:ness-logger:jar:1.0.0` but `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.7.9` includes a newer version `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:2.7.2`

My solution was to exclude kafaka_2.11 from my ness-logger dependency like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.company.riptide.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>ness-logger</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Truncated output of `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] +- my.company.riptide.api:ness-logger:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.5.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.55:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- my.company.eis:ness-logging-package:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:0.10.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.101tec:zkclient:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:jar:2.5.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- my.company.riptide.springboot:graceful-shutdown:jar:1.0.2:compile

[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.5-6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:jar:7.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:7.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:7.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-messages:jar:7.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:messages:jar:17.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:4.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:13.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:7.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:7.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:7.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:html-formatter:jar:17.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- io.cucumber:create-meta:jar:6.0.1:test

[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.7.9:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:5.18.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-raft:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.13:jar:2.12.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.12.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.13:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.13:jar:0.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.13.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.13:jar:3.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper-jute:jar:3.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:test:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.2:test
```